# vim recognize as javascript

Tags: javascript, vim

I'd like to make any file which begins with `#!/usr/bin/env node` be recognized as JavaScript.

I know Vim does this with other languages, like BASH, so there must be a way of doing it.

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/366629/set-file-type-in-vim-according-to-the-hashbang-line

Comment: This is because *vim* determines file type from `#!/usr/bin/env` part. Not `#!/usr/bin/env node` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code snippet to your .vimrc or to another file
and source it in .vimrc:

```
if did_filetype()
  finish
endif
if getline(1) =~ '#!/usr/bin/env node'
  setfiletype javascript                                                      
endif
```

This simply sets the filetype to js when the first line of the
file matches '#!/usr/bin/env node' - pretty much self explanatory.
This is described in the filetype help as well - check :he filetype

Answer (score 1):

Find path of `node` by `whereis node` comamnd. Then use it as `#!/path/to/node`. This will only work if vim can recognize your script for `/path/to/node` or by extension.